# Update Field In .plist

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I have plist given below

i have to update field in plist

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Pad</key>
    <array>
        <string>Person</string>
        <string>Father</string>
    </array>
    <key>Phone</key>
    <array>
        <string>Person</string>
        <string>Father</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

i have used code below to add new field

```
 let file : NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("me", withExtension: "plist")!
    let pilistDic : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfURL: file)!

    pilistDic.setObject("new", forKey: "key")
    pilistDic.writeToFile(String(file), atomically: true)
```

Comment: What you're asking is unclear - did your method of adding a new item not work?

Comment: If you want help then you need to describe the specific problem you're having. What does the code that you've posted do when you run it? If you are getting an error, what is the error, and one what line? (In this particular case I know why it's not working, but you need to provide details)

Comment: Always make the question clear and understandable to the viewers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if plist attached in Bundle, it cannot be updated using writeToFile.
You will be able to update the plist located in document directory.